# Rest server (Play Framework) gets "Read Timed out" exception during load test

Tags: rest, playframework, jmeter, load-testing

We are running a heavy load test (jmeter: 350 threads, 35M total requests) on a rest server using Play Framework and run into the following error after ~2 hour. We remove other components so that request simply take requests and do nothing. Anyone has any idea or simply Play Framework cannot handle heavy load like this?

```
2014/07/05 11:59:38 WARN  - com.company.test.RestTest2: Run TestSQL throw error java.lang.Exception: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at com.company.dispatcher.RexsterRESTTaskDispatcher.dispatchTask(RexsterRESTTaskDispatcher.java:76)
        at com.company.test.RestTest2.runTest(RestTest2.java:375)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:191)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Part of the application.conf :
....

```
db.pool.timeout=100000

play {
  akka {
    akka.loggers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger", "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 64
          parallelism-max = 1000
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the this error today. It tool me a while to found out that one of the windows (`svchost`) processes was occupying the 1099 port, which the Jmeter server was trying to use.

I got a hint for this when trying to start the `Jmeter-Server.bat` file manually. Then, the following PowerShell command provided the details of that process. After closing that process, Jmeter clients started to connect again.

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 1099).OwningProcess
```

Answer (score -1):

There a many things to check:

- Are you running Test from same machine ? if yes it's a problem
- Is your machine TCP stack tuned ?
- What is your JVM configuration regarding Xmx as long as your machine memory, CPU ...
- What does your test look like ? could you show a screenshot with all elements unfolded ?

I think Play/AKKA can handle this load without problem so I would look into configuration issues.