# Play framework hanging

Tags: rest, playframework, jmeter, load-testing

Related to question in 
[Rest server (Play Framework) gets "Read Timed out" exception during load test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588084/rest-server-play-framework-gets-read-timed-out-exception-during-load-test?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

I have similar situation using play framework 2.2.4:

java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)

I am testing play with jmeter in my local PC. I hit with 2000 threads and timeout exception occurs, and Socket is somehow not closing.

How do I catch this exception and close the hanging sockets?

StackTrace:

```
va.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:169) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3640) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread.blockOn(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:167) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$.get(FPromiseHelper.scala:53) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper.get(FPromiseHelper.scala) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.libs.F$Promise.get(F.java:363) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
wrap response>>
        at com.ganda.common.controllers.filters.WrapResponse.wrap(WrapResponse.java:50) ~[na:na]
db filter below>>>
        at com.ganda.common.controllers.filters.CredentialsFilter.call(CredentialsFilter.java:72) ~[na:na]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
Wrapped by: play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 seconds]]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:264) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:260) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$1.execute(Execution.scala:43) [play-iteratees_2.10.jar:2.2.4]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library.jar:na]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What is happening here is that the Play promise is timeouting probably due to slow down introduced by load.

So this reveals a performance issue in your application, you could if it's acceptable increase the promise timeout or profile and improve performances of the promise processing so that it proceeds faster.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is performance issue being fixed. there is lots of information for deploing play in   http://ebooks24.org/9781617290909.html and using HAProxy + load ballancing pretty much solve the hanging socket.